# How to find perpendicular lines through a specific point

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

I need find the line perpendicular to another line (defined by two points it passes through) and intersects a specific point (defined by its coordinates). I need to calculate the length of the segement of the line I need to find between the line it is perpendicular to and the point. It is similar to how finding the height of a triangle works. In the example below the line would be defined by the points: A(0, 0), B(4, 1) and the point it should intersect would be C(-1, 2).
[image: example]
I know this can easily be calculated with the pythagoras theorem but it just throws me off when the line isn't vertical/horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make vectors

```
AB = (abx, aby) = (B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y)
AC = (acx, acy) = (C.x - A.x, C.y - A.y)
```

The simplest form of projection of `C` onto `A—B` line, using the dot product, is:

```
AD = AB * (AB dot AC) / (AB dot AB)
D = (dx, dy) = A + AD
```

In coordinates:

```
coeff = (abx*acx + aby*acy) / (abx*abx+aby*aby)
dx = A.x + abx * coeff
dy = A.y + aby * coeff
```

`D` point is projection of `C` onto `A—B` line. If you need `CD` length, get

```
CDlen = sqrt((cx-dx)^2+(cy-dy)^2)
```

(or use `Math.Hypot` function in some languages)